# QSocketNotifier - How to use it to watch a file? - linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, inotify

I want my c++ application to watch for changes in a file called "aaa". I want to do it by QSocketNotifier. I didn't understand from the documentation how to do it. Can you please send me a sample?

10!

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use QFileSystemWatcher?

Answer (score 4):

Use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfilesystemwatcher.html). It performs all the inotify hackery for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsocketnotifier.html) class works with sockets, not files. Since it apparently uses [select(2)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/select/) under the hood, you *might* get away with passing it a file descriptor returned by [inotify_init()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/inotify_init.2.html) and trick it into monitoring file changes that way. That's highly doubtful, though.